# IVsOutputWindow reference not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

I want to write to visual studio output window in my add in. I found a code from
[How do I write to the Visual Studio Output Window in My Custom Tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094366/how-do-i-write-to-the-visual-studio-output-window-in-my-custom-tool)
But I can't add a reference to **IVsOutputWindow**. 
There is no any namespace like **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop**
and also no dll. 
How should I fix this problem

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're having trouble locating the `IVsOutputWindow` interface.  If so here is the information on that type

- Namespace: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop`
- DLL: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop

If the SDK is install on your machine the DLL will be located in the following directory

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll

The top 2 directories may change though based on the operating system and version of the SDK you are using.  If this doesn't work please let me know the SDK version you are using and I'll try and point you to the correct path.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying me. I am using Visual Studio 2008. I searched in my hard drive for that dll. But there is no any. But I found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop from C:\Windows\assembly folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to actually download and install the Visual Studio SDK - it's a separate download that's not included with Visual Studio itself. Once installed, I restarted Visual Studio, and the necessary assemblies were listed when I went to add references to my project.