# Debugging Roslyn Analyzer

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-2015

I am working on writing a `DiagnosticAnalyzer`.  I was able to unit test it just fine.  I wanted to try it out in Visual Studio.  The VSIX project that got created seems to be working.  When I set that to the default project and Run the solution another instance of VS launches and I can see that my VSIX got installed.  However when I set breakpoints it shows that the symbols aren't loaded and the breakpoint won't be hit.  Anyone have any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653486/how-to-debug-a-vsix-project ?

Comment: Have you made sure, that you have installed the correct version of the ".NET Compiler Platform SDK Templates" extension? I had the same problem and noticed that I had installed the wrong version. I'm using CTP 6 of VS2015 so I had to install ".NET Compiler Platform SDK Templates for CTP6". After that I've been able to debug the analyzer extension just like any other program.

Comment: I think that was it! Thanks. I had the older SDK and templates installed. Not sure how I did that, but fixed now. If you add it as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you made sure, that you have installed the correct version of the ".NET Compiler Platform SDK Templates" extension? I had the same problem and noticed that I had installed the wrong version. I'm using CTP 6 of VS2015 so I had to install ".NET Compiler Platform SDK Templates for CTP6" ([Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ecefb773-36a6-4316-98db-4a87ed8cf5dc)). After that I've been able to debug the analyzer extension just like any other program.