# Can I not debug the ITestExecutor methods in a unit test adapter?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Using the sample project from [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/31/writing-a-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-adapter.aspx), I'm writing a custom unit test adapter. I'm able to debug it with the experimental instance in visual studio, set breakpoints, and see `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` output, and it all works beautifully for almost all of my methods. I can see evidence that it's working (as in the outputs of the test cases are what I expect if I fiddle with the error message, duration, etc).

However, for the methods in my test executor class (deriving from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.ITestExecutor`), I neither hit my breakpoints nor see any of my trace output. Is there a setting or something to make that work? I'm wondering if the test execution framework is doing some kind of optimization on this class that makes it harder to debug.

Thank you.

Comment: One workaround is to open a separate log file as a `System.IO.StreamWriter` and just write to it. I still don't get why I can't write to the Output window with `Trace.WriteLine()` though from this particular class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to attach the debugger to the process `vstest.executionengine.x86.exe`, which is a child spawned by `devenv.exe`. I'm assuming the same trick applies to `vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe` for the test discovery code.

Bonus Question: Is there a way to set up the debugger to attach to those automatically when I debug my unit test adapter project?

Comment: You can [configure this per exe name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.100).aspx). You can also call [Debugger.Launch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx) in your ITestExecutor