# How to debug the extension DLL in CodedUITest?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am implementing coded ui support for my control , i am using custom properties for my control, so i have written extension file and paste it in below location
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTT\11.0\UITestExtensionPackages

Now i want to debug the extension file, when Cross-Hair detect the UIElements.

How to do any help?

Comment: Very similar question asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281662/how-to-debug-visual-studio-extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about "Way to debug the CodedUITest plugin dll" means, please follow the below steps

1) Create your plugin extension to show custom properties and more 
2) Set the output path of plugin project as C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTT\11.0\UITestExtensionPackages-- (For this you need to run the Visual Studio in Administrator mode) 
3) Set the break point at where you want and Build the plugin project 
4) Create your test project and execute it by "Generate CodedUITest for ..." . Builder will be displayed at bottom right corner of your machine. 
5) Run your application exe( for ex: Application1.exe) 
6) Now in Plugin Project, do the follow steps,
- GoTo Tools Menu 
- Click AttachToProcess 
- Window will open and choose your CodedUITestBuilder application from list of process( means builder window in right corner) 
7) Now drag the crosshair from builder to your application UI and **See Breakpoint will hit**