# Debugging Visual Studio Template/Extension throws NotInstalledException

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-templates

Running Visual Studio 2013, I'm trying to debug a Visual Studio project template, as well as a visual studio extension.  I've followed the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281662/how-to-debug-visual-studio-extensions), but when the new instance of Visual Studio launches, I get:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.NotInstalledException was
>   unhandled Message: An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.NotInstalledException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

I've tried disabling all Visual Studio Extensions (that can be) - that didn't help.