# Run Visual studio vs package in custom Hive (not Exp)

Tags: vspackage

I'm developing a VsPackage and try to test it under Hive other then the Exp.

I created a new Hive using the vs developer command prompt using the following command: *devenv /rootsuffix MyExp*
And than run VS with */rootsuffix MyExp* command line arguments, but failed to make my extension work on that hive . Only when I run it under the Exp it work.

The main reason that I don't want to run it under the Exp hive is that I don't want to effects other extension on the hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the 'Exp' string under my package project sub folders.
I found the place that declares to where the VSSDK build tool will copy my vs-package.

On my machine, under my vs-package folder:

*MyPackage\packages\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.14.1.24720\tools\vssdk\Microsoft.VsSDK.Common.targets* file.

I change the value in VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix under PropertyGroup section from:

```
<VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix Condition="'$(VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix)' == ''">*Exp*</VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix>
```

to:

```
 <VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix Condition="'$(VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix)' == ''">*MyExp*</VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix>
```

MyExp is the name of my new Hive.

Comment: in case you don't find the exact file. find the folloing path at the vsix project packages sub folders, 
<VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix Condition="'$(VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix)' == ''">*Exp*</VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix>
and replace "EXP" with your Hive name. don't forget to change on the project properties -> Debug --> Command line arguments the hive name also thier

Comment: You shouldn't modify files in the NuGet package folder. Instead, set the `VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix` property in your `.csproj` directly. As long as there's a value present, the condition on the XML you show will stop it from replacing the value from your `.csproj`.