# How to create and install test adapter in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I want' to create a protractor test adapter for Visual Studio. I have found I can create it with implementing ITestExecutor and ITestDiscoverer.
I follow the Marcel De Vries documentation (https://xpirit.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Xpirit-magazine-2-Protractor-UI-testing.pdf) but I can't found how to add my extension in Visual Studio.

- I have tried to add my assembly directly in the \Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Extensions folder.
- I have tried to create a Vsix and install it. (with UnitTestExtension as Asset)
- I have tried to download Marcel's project (https://github.com/XpiritBV/ProtractorAdapter) compile and install it.

It's not work, the command "vstest.console.exe /listdiscoverers /UseVsixExtensions:true" doesn't list my discoverer. And JS tests don't found by VS.

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Read up on creating VSIX projects.

Comment: Ok, i have found why vstest don't work. A very ugly mistake of my. I have been in the wrong visual studio folder. I'll continue to understand the Microsoft Test implementation.

Comment: If anyone struggles with VS 2017, the correct path to put your adapter in is _Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\Extensions_.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation is very poor for creating test adapter for VS. There are many URL that can help to understand how implement UTE with JS automated test :

- http://matthewmanela.com/blog/anatomy-of-the-chutzpah-test-adapter-for-vs-2012-rc/
- https://xpirit.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Xpirit-magazine-2-Protractor-UI-testing.pdf
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bhuvaneshwari/2012/03/13/authoring-a-new-visual-studio-unit-test-adapter/

In summary :
Step 1 :

- we need to implement ITestExecutor to launch test with protractor
  prompt command and return the result.
- we need to implement ITestDiscoverer to parse file in argument to find all tests inside.

You can test this primary version without VSix : Go to Visual studio Test extension folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Extensions for VS 2013) and add your DLL and dependencies. Try to launch tests with commands like that  in windows command prompt :

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow  
vstest.console.exe "c:\test\test.js"
```

Step 2 :
By default Visual Studio only parse .dll and .exe files. If you want to parse another file type (.lua, .js, ...) you need to create a parser who explicitly browse source files and find all tests.
You need to create implement two Interfaces :

- ITestContainerDiscoverer
- ITestContainer

This project (https://github.com/XpiritBV/ProtractorAdapter) will be useful to understand how implement that and how adapt your code to subscribe on any changes in your project (Add file, Edit file, Project Load, etc.).

Important : You need to create a VSix project to test that ! If not, Visual Studio don't load your TestContaineDiscoverer.

Important 2 : When you create a VSix file, you need to explain two Assets :

- Type : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent / Path : |YourProject|
- Type : UnitTestExtension / Path |YourProject|

Hope it's help somebody.

Comment: How do you debug any issues that maybe there in a test adapter?

Comment: You can lauchn VS in debug mode (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281662/how-to-debug-visual-studio-extensions). But I have encountered difficulties with that, so I have used the old and ugliest way : Write logs in a file.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to run the test adapter with vstest.console.exe but don't need visual studio integration you will need to do the following:

- Create a project that is a class library
- ***Very important:*** The assembly name **must** end with **.TestAdapter** or vstest.console.exe will not recognize your test adapter. You can change this setting in the properties of your project.
- Import **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel** which for me was located at **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll**
- You only need to implement **ITestDiscoverer** and **ITestExecutor**
- If your test adapter is for **.dll** or **.exe** files the default test adapter will run first. I could not find a way to disable this.

The above accepted answer and code was very useful for me when figuring out how to create a test adapter. Be aware that if you are creating a VSIX then the asset type **UnitTestExtension** is not available in the list but seems to work and can be added in the .vsixmanifest file manually.

Additional useful links:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2012/03/03/how-to-make-your-extension-visible-to-the-test-explorer-in-visual-studio-11/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/07/31/writing-a-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-adapter/
- https://blog.dantup.com/2014/02/some-things-i-learned-while-building-my-visual-studio-test-adapter/

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but as of today (2022) I'd suggest to read through the docs mentioned in official MS Visual Studio Test Platform [readme](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest#documentation).

Also, watching this [Exploring the Visual Studio Test Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/shows/on-net/exploring-the-visual-studio-test-platform) episode, altough dated, might help.

Comment: The content you are pointing to I don't think even existed when this question was asked. The top answer should be marked as obsolete.

Comment: Definitely did not exist, dev experience for this piece of VS changed a nr of times in the past. I don't know about SO policies about obsolete contents. If you're right and the answer is *that* useful, eventually will receive so many upvotes to become the most voted (I don't think it'll happen, BTW)

Comment: Its been known to happen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42966511/6438779

:thinking: Unfortunately, I would be surprised if enough of us were writing custom test adapters though. 

They don't mention anything about enabling the green play button in the IDE. I can ask a separate question - but do you happen to know anything about that? My adapter reads dlls, I thought it should #justwork, but while tests will run in the IDE - the play button does not appear.

Comment: @PaulG sorry for late reply, I completely missed that. I've been far for too long from test adapter area. At the time, "it just worked": when I was in VS, inside a test project file, and there was an adapter installed for that type of test project, I could push the play button in the test runner panel at the bottom. I remember I could also switch some .Net framework version or something in the top menu bar (as I had issues with that and asked here on SO)

Comment: BTW in the python question you referenced, there is a more recent, most voted answer yet the accepted answer is still the older one :) (that's what I was trying to say before)

Comment: For future travellers - I ended up working out how to accomplish this custom test adapter - its now implemented over in https://github.com/paulegradie/Sailfish