# Can you run a Apache JMeter load test through Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise?

Tags: apache, testing, jmeter, load, visual-studio-2017

So I have a JMeter load test that is running in VSTS. I was wondering if it is at all possible to run this test through Visual Studio itself? I would be interested in viewing more details about the test through Application Insights.

The JMeter test is running in the cloud. I know about load test projects in Visual Studio, but is there a way to add the JMeter tests from VSTS?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to add/run Apache JMeter load test through VS 2017.

There are many ways to run JMeter test: [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui).

You can try to create a test adapter and call test through command line. [How to create and install test adapter in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100057/how-to-create-and-install-test-adapter-in-visual-studio)