# NUnitLite results display in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, nunit, visual-studio-2019

NUnitLite is really useful for Autocad/Bricscad plugin testing, because i can load plugin, and then manually, from inside of an assembly, invoke tests `new AutoRun().Execute(nunitArgs);` Thanks to CADbloke [github repository](https://github.com/CADbloke/CADtest) for tutorial on how to do this.

NUnitLite test results are saved to a xml file and can be converted to HTML ([ReportUnit](https://github.com/reportunit/reportunit) or [ExtentReports](https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-csharp) ) and opened with browser.

---

Is there a way to connect NUnitLite with Visual Studio 2019 Test Explorer or to NUnit GUI, so i can automatically see results there? Or some non automatic way?

Bonus question:
Is it possible to manually invoke NUnit tests (from assembly) in other way than using NUnitLite?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the key use cases for which NUnitLite is designed. Unfortunately, since NUnitLite is nothing more than a console application, there is no way for it to transmit test results back to TestExplorer. It would have to be enhanced to function as some sort of agent using a communications channel - not impossible but definitely non-trivial, especially when used "inside" your AutoCad plugin.

Comment: Thanks for answer, things are more clear now!

Anyway, NUnitLite is really a rescuer. I will make another answer with some details for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

After some research on the topic, i decided to share information i have found for future readers (and maybe future me :) )

Since NUnitLite outputs .xml file with test results, my idea was to somehow load and show these results to Test Explorer in Visual Studio. I have found some articles which explain how to do it, and basically you need to create Test Adapter - it loads data from .xml file and doesn't run any tests, but returns test results (looks like mocking tests - we can't just load results into Test Explorer).

I decided not to go further for now because: 1) i am not sure how much time will be needed, 2) i will get only readonly test results, without possibility to use features of Test Explorer - and this already exists as html preview.

---

Here are some blogs that could be helpful:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/writing-a-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-adapter/
- https://blog.dantup.com/2014/02/some-things-i-learned-while-building-my-visual-studio-test-adapter/
- http://matthewmanela.com/blog/anatomy-of-the-chutzpah-test-adapter-for-vs-2012-rc/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2012/03/03/how-to-make-your-extension-visible-to-the-test-explorer-in-visual-studio-11/

Of course check NUnit test adapter, it is adapter that works:

- https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter

And some forum posts, with useful information:

- [How to create and install test adapter in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100057/how-to-create-and-install-test-adapter-in-visual-studio)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ecdcbff-4c1b-43c0-8988-6071255a4f7e/plug-custom-unit-tests-into-visual-studios-test-explorer?forum=vcgeneral
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ecdcbff-4c1b-43c0-8988-6071255a4f7e/plug-custom-unit-tests-into-visual-studios-test-explorer?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: Nice idea. I'll think about doing it one of these days. :-)

Comment: Nice, i'm curious about it :)