# How to create an adapter for the Visual Studio Test Explorer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I'm a bit stuck with the problem of creating a custom adapter for the Visual Studio test explorer.
(Btw I'm using VS 2019). I need to create my own test framework, for sure, with my own test attributes, that the Test Explorer can detect.
Just a little bit of information I could find while researching and I tried the suggested solutions but it didn't work for me:

1. Create a project and implement ITestRunner and ITestDiscoverer. Copy the output .dll to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Extensions". Of course, it created a test adapter for test running and executed my tests well, but not discovered any one using Visual Studio.
2. Create a nuget package from this project and add it to a target project.
3. Download source code of NUnit and tried to analyze but, actually, I didn't find any point that describes a test discovering for the Test Explorer of VS. But if I try to create a nuget package locally from this source project of NUnit, it works. All test can be found by test explorer using NUnit test attribute.

Can anyone help me, what is a right way to do the integration with the Visual Studio Test Explorer?

Comment: I think you should create the [build-in vsix project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019) and then implements such interface in it. The vsix project works for vs-sdk. You can use that project template to extend the feature of VS IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but for anyone coming afterwards:
you might want to look at this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100057/how-to-create-and-install-test-adapter-in-visual-studio) and e.g. [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72120983/540776).