# Problems discovering tests automatically using the TestPlatform in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I am developing a unit testing framework with C#. I am using the official `Microsoft.TestPlatform` library and I have already implemented `ITestDiscoverer` and `ITestExecutor`.

What I am using to determine that a method is a test is the `MyTestAttribute` attribute.

`MyTestAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyTestAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

`TestDiscoverer`:

```
[DefaultExecutorUri(Constants.ExecutorUriString)]
[FileExtension(".dll")]
internal class TestDiscoverer : ITestDiscoverer
{
    public void DiscoverTests(IEnumerable<string> sources, IDiscoveryContext discoveryContext, IMessageLogger logger, ITestCaseDiscoverySink discoverySink)
    {
        //Discover tests code
        //If the method use MyTestAttribute is a test
    }
}
```

`TestExecutor`:

```
[ExtensionUri(Constants.ExecutorUriString)]
internal class TestExecutor : ITestExecutor
{
    public void Cancel()
    {
        //Cancel code
    }

    public void RunTests(IEnumerable<TestCase>? testCases, IRunContext? runContext, IFrameworkHandle? frameworkHandle)
    {
        //Run tests code
    }

    public void RunTests(IEnumerable<string>? sources, IRunContext? runContext, IFrameworkHandle? frameworkHandle)
    {
        //Run tests code
    }
}
```

So far everything works well, if I have a method that uses the `[MyTest]` attribute when I run the tests it is detected.

```
[MyTest]
public void Should_Be_A_Test()
{
    //Unit test code
}
```

[image: test explorer result]

The problem is that the test is only visible in the test explorer once I run it, and not when the test is created. To better visualize the problem I am going to show a comparison with the xUnit framework, which is the behavior I want to achieve.

Creation of tests:

- MyFramework

```
[MyTest]
public void Should_Be_A_Test()
{
    //Unit test code
}
```

- xUnit

```
[Fact]
public void Should_Be_True()
{
    Assert.True(true);
}
```

**Test explorer results**

Before running the tests

[image: test explorer result]

As you can see in the image, just by creating the test in xUnit it is already detected, but the methods that use `MyTest` are not detected.

After running the tests

[image: test explorer result]

Once I run the tests, it is detected and works correctly.

My question is, how can I reproduce that behavior that xUnit has?

I tried to find how to do it in xUnit by looking at the source code but I couldn't find how to do it.

Comment: You should look for a way to execute your test discovery as post build event.

Comment: It seems like you have to implement  ITestContainerDiscoverer. Please have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100057/how-to-create-and-install-test-adapter-in-visual-studio