Custom Test Adapter for VS 2022
I faced an issue with creating of test adapter for custom test runner (it doesn't use mstest, nunit and so on under the hood).
So, these tests runs via custom .exe file and VS doesn't see these tests (not appears into the test explorer).
I found few links with info regarding the test adapter (how to create it, how to add into VS).
But, I tried a lot of different ways, they doesn't work at all. I added my test adapter as vsix, as nuget package, as dll using vstest.console.exe (I even fully cope example of XmlTestAdapter).
It doesn't work unfortunately,
I used this link as base:
https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/blob/main/docs/RFCs/0004-Adapter-Extensibility.md
I did everything the same like in this page (all interfaces, all attributes, .runsettings file), but I still don't see the custom discoverer and tests in total
And it would be great if someone could ask, how to debug it (vsix, nuget)
Guys, do you have a good example of it that works for VS 2022, or maybe you can help to deal with it, please
I see that package was installed, there are no errors and in this case I can not understand was it added or not correctly
[FileExtension(".dll")]
[DefaultExecutorUri(ExecutorUriString.ExecutorString)]
public class CustomTestDiscoverer : ITestDiscoverer
{
    public void DiscoverTests(
        IEnumerable<string> sources,
        IDiscoveryContext discoveryContext,
        IMessageLogger logger,
        ITestCaseDiscoverySink discoverySink)
    {
        logger.SendMessage(TestMessageLevel.Informational, "Start test discoverer");
        foreach (var source in sources)
        {
            logger.SendMessage(TestMessageLevel.Informational, $"Check source file: {source}");
            GetTests(source).ToList().ForEach(discoverySink.SendTestCase);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TestCase> GetTests(string source)
    {
        var tests = new List<TestCase>();
        var testClassAttr = "TestClass";
        var testCaseAttr = "TestCase";
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(source);
        var testClasses = assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.BaseType.Name.EndsWith(testClassAttr)).ToList();
        var methods = testClasses.SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods())
            .Where(method => method.CustomAttributes.Any(attr => attr.AttributeType.Name.EndsWith(testCaseAttr)))
            .ToList();
        methods.ForEach(method =>
        {
            var attr = method.CustomAttributes.First(attr => attr.AttributeType.Name.EndsWith(testCaseAttr));
            tests.Add(new TestCase(method.Name, ExecutorUriString.ExecutorUri, source));
        });
        return tests;
    }
}

[ExtensionUri(ExecutorUriString.ExecutorString)]
public class CustomTestExecutor : ITestExecutor
{
    private bool _isCanceled = false;

    public void Cancel()
    {
        _isCanceled = true;
    }

    public void RunTests(IEnumerable<TestCase>? tests, IRunContext? runContext, IFrameworkHandle? frameworkHandle)
    {
        foreach (var test in tests)
        {
            if (_isCanceled) break;
            var result = new TestResult(test)
            {
                Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed,
                ErrorMessage = "Error message if any",
                ErrorStackTrace = "Stack trace if any"
            };
            frameworkHandle.RecordResult(result);
        }
    }

    public void RunTests(IEnumerable<string>? sources, IRunContext? runContext, IFrameworkHandle? frameworkHandle)
    {
        var tests = new List<TestCase>();
        foreach (var path in sources)
        {
            if (_isCanceled) break;
            tests.AddRange(CustomTestDiscoverer.GetTests(path));
        }
        RunTests(tests, runContext, frameworkHandle);
    }
}

Implement requested interfaces, used Microsoft instruction, added this test adapter as vsix, nuget, simple dll, tried to see the test discoverer via vstest.console

Why not look at the NUnit and xUnit test adapters? They're open source so you can check how they're implemented, how they can be tested and how they can be packaged.  Check eg xunit.runner.visualstudio.

Have you read the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100057/how-to-create-and-install-test-adapter-in-visual-studio?

@MinxinYu-MSFT Yes, I tried to copy fully XML Test Adapter (re-create) from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bhuvaneshwari/authoring-a-new-visual-studio-unit-test-adapter
Also, xunit, it doesn't work, I don't know

According to the thread:  How to create and install test adapter in Visual Studio
Use GitHub sample: https://github.com/XpiritBV/ProtractorAdapter
Put DLL (e.g. Protractor.TestAdapter.dll) at folder Visual Studio install folder .....\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\Extensions
CMD to list :  vstest.console.exe /listdiscoverers


It doesn't work for me, I don't see the discoverer

Did you successfully build the project ProtractorTestAdapter?

I see the protractor discoverer, it doesn't work for mine test adapter :(

The assembly name must end with .TestAdapter or vstest.console.exe will not recognize your test adapter. Such as Protractor.TestAdapter.dll

I found an issue. It wasn't a name. It was type of project, I used Class Library (.net) - .net8, but when I recreate it with just Class Library (4.8) it started to work.
